# GraphQL argument passing

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I start to learning graphql. But I can't pass the arguments. when I console.log the args, that is undefined. I want to pass the name value of `greeting` from a client and pass it as an argument.

```
//schema
//resolvers

import { GraphQLServer } from "graphql-yoga";

//Scalar type: string, Boolean, Int, Float, ID
// ! must return same scalar type
// type name always cap

const typeDefs= `
type Query{
    greeting(name: String): String!
    me: User!
    post: Post!
}

type User{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    age: Int
}
type Post{
    id:ID!
    title: String!
    body: String!
}
`
//age value is not must
//resolvers get four args parent,args,ctx,info

const resolvers={
    Query:{
        greeting:(args)=>{
            console.log(args)
            return `Konika said to ${args.name}`
        },
        me:()=>{
            return{
                id:"12345",
                name: "jalmal",
                email: "ja@gmail.com",
                age: null
            }
        },
        post:()=>{
            return{
                id: "12345",
                title:"I am ok with it",
                body:"Why I am failed"
            }
        }
       
    }
}

const server = new GraphQLServer({typeDefs, resolvers})
server.start(()=>console.log(`server is running`));
```

my query is like this

```
query{
  greeting(name: "milar")
  me{
    id
    email
    age
  }
  post{
    id
    title
  }
}
```

I can't find why args is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The `args` from the client-side are passed as the second parameter of a resolver. See [Root fields & resolvers](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#root-fields-resolvers)

It should be:

```js
const resolvers={
    Query:{
        greeting:(_, args)=>{
            console.log(args)
            return `Konika said to ${args.name}`
        }
    }
}
```